# How to convert large image files in c#

Tags: c#

I have several large image files that I need to convert to different image formats. I am using the following code to do this:

```
using (Image img =new Bitmap(inputImageName))
        {
            img.Save(outputImageName, imageFormat);
        }
```

It do the conversation, but also since the images are big, it generate outofmemory exception. I read several articles about how to overcome fragmentation of LOH, but I cannot use any of them in this case.

What Can I do?

The images are around 100MByte and it happens after opening 3 or 4 images.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  How big are the images?  Does this happen with one image?  After ten?

Comment: What does this have to do with WPF? In fact, the library you are using is meant to be used with WinForms, not WPF.

Comment: @KendallFrey: you are right, this is winform library, but the application is a wpf. If here is a better way to do this in WPF, then I am more than happy to use the WPF version.

Answer (score 3):

The question you need to ask here is "Do I have to do this in .NET and / or C#"

While I can see why that to many folks a flexible language like C# may be the answer to performing many tasks, I also have to say that "When All you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a Nail"

If this is a one time conversion, and you only need to use them for one project, then my advice to you is to use a stand alone tool better suited for the Job.

There are tons out there ranging from paid applications like:

AcdSee Photo Manager

http://www.acdsee.com/

to free tools such as

Ifran View and it's image conversion functions

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic50519.html

If command line scripting is your game, then use a tool set such as ImageMagik:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Iamage Magik also has .NET bindings so it's functionality can be used from within .NET projects as well as many others if your project requires that you convert these on the fly in your program code.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php

For scenarios like this one there really is no reason to re-invent the wheel, this problem has been solved so many times before that it really is not a decision you should have to make.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at WPF image manipulation classes, which do not use GDI, according to [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/12/10/resizing-images-from-the-server-using-wpf-wic-instead-of-gdi.aspx). The following source code is a good starting point :

```
public static void Resize(string input, string output)
{
    using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(input))
    {
        var photoDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(inputStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.None);

        var frame = photoDecoder.Frames[0];

        using (var ouputStream = File.Create(output))
        {
            var targetEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            targetEncoder.Frames.Add(frame);
            targetEncoder.Save(ouputStream);
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have anything to do with the Large Object Heap.  The Bitmap class is a managed wrapper for GDI+ and GDI+ is a big chunk of unmanaged code.  It allocates pixel data buffers in unmanaged memory.  The amount of managed memory your code uses is very small.

A 100 megabyte image file doesn't say much about how much unmanaged memory is required.  In all likelihood it is a compressed image format, like JPEG or PNG.  Which does require a great deal more unmanaged memory after it is uncompressed.  So you could easily end up needing hundreds of megabytes.

And that's a problem when you run your code on a 32-bit operating system or you've selected the x86 as your EXE's platform target setting (the default on VS2010 and up).  Your program allocates virtual memory from the holes that are available between the chunks of code and data that are already loaded.  GDI+ requires a contiguous chunk of memory to load the pixel data and that can be hard to come by when your program has lots of available virtual memory but it is spread among many holes.  An additional problem is *address space fragmentation*, loading a DLL or allocating memory could cut the size of a large hole in two.

There's a simple fix available for this problem, run your code on a 64-bit operating system.  It has gobs of virtual memory available, big holes.  The odds that you can do anything about your current problem on a 32-bit operating system are slim to none.  You have no direct control over the memory manager.